# SOAP with Node.js & arguments spreading

Tags: node.js, soap

I have to consume a SOAP API which is basically designed for PHP and has always been user with a PHP client. Problem is, I work with Node.js, and I encounter an issue I cannot handle.
Here is a part of "could-be-working" code :

```
<?php
try {
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => "https://my-soap-server.com/_soap/server.php",
        'uri' => "https://my-soap-server.com",
        'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1'
    ));
    $result = $client->myMethod('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');
    var_dump($result);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring:{$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

As you can see, arguments are passed to myMethod with a specific order, and not as an object.
With node's soap client (node-soap or strong-soap), argument 2 must be the callback, which can give a code quite like this : (let's say the documentation gives me field 1 should be 'login', etc)

```
const soap = require('soap');

soap
    .createClientAsync('http://my-soap-server.com')
    .then((client) => client.myMethod({
        login: 'aaaa',
        password: 'bbbb',
        randomVar: 'cccc',
    }, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log(result);
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Well, I do not have any error, but the API does not do what it is expected to do.
So, I guess the issue is that the server does not expect an object with keys, but the arguments, spred in a certain order, just like in PHP. Is there a way to reproduce that with Node.js ?

I hope I have been clear enough.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT : Maybe easier with the [WSDL](https://eml-srv.com/_soap/control.php?WSDL), method I want to get working is Ajout_BDD.

EDIT 2 : Well, after further investigation, it looks like the SOAP request from PHP and the one from Node.js were really different in format.
So I made it simpler (and, unfortunately, dirtier) by using "request" lib from node and making a template from the working PHP request.
FYI, you can dump PHP SOAP requests with the following code :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1:2018/test/test2?WSDL", array(
    'trace' => 1
));
[...]
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

You can also dump the Node SOAP request this way :

```
soap.createClientAsync('http://my-soap-server/hello?WSDL', (error, client) => client.myMethod({
    login: 'aaaa',
    password: 'bbbb',
    randomVar: 'cccc',
}, (error, result) => {
    [...]
    console.log(client.lastRequest);
}));
```

Then just use your favorite comparator to see what differs between your calls.

Comment: That is a tricky one, it's hard to see exactly what the problem is with your Node.js SOAP request without having access to the service in question. What is really useful in this context is to see a trace of the actual web traffic. 

Something like WireShark is really useful here, you can see what your request from PHP looks like and compare it to your request in Node.js. I've encountered problems like this and I can see very quickly what is different between the two SOAP calls.

Comment: That's a good method of solving the problem, its useful to have the ability to inspect the exact SOAP requests to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested out the WSDL provided in the link, a SOAP call to the Ajout_BDD procedure will involve a HTTP post that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:typens="urn:mdworks">
    <soap:Body>
        <typens:Ajout_BDD>
            <login>loginValue</login>
            <moddepasse>moddepasseValue</moddepasse>
            <bdd>bddValue</bdd>
            <ligne>
                <typens:someField>someFieldValue</typens:someField>
            </ligne>
        </typens:Ajout_BDD>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the response should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:typens="urn:mdworks">
    <soap:Body>
        <typens:Ajout_BDDResponse>
            <typens:output>
                <typens:Ajout_BDDReturn>true</typens:Ajout_BDDReturn>
            </typens:output>
        </typens:Ajout_BDDResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

There should be nothing specific about the service that needs a PHP client to call it. In Node.js your client side code should look like this:

```
"use strict";

var url = 'http://localhost:8001/mdworksService';
var wsdlFileName = 'example-service-original.wsdl';

const soap = require('soap');
const path = require('path');

soap
    .createClientAsync(path.join(__dirname, wsdlFileName), {endpoint: url})
    .then((client) => client.Ajout_BDD({
        login: 'loginValue', moddepasse: 'moddepasseValue', bdd: 'bddValue', ligne: { someField: 'someFieldValue'}
    }, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log(result);
        process.exit(0);
    }))
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

You need to replace the url with the actual URL of the service and also create the WSDL file (using the WSDL you linked to). It's easy to create a Node.js Mock of this service for the purposes of testing your client side code. You can do something like:

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');

var service = {
    mdworksService: {
        MDWORKSPort: {
            Ajout_BDD : function(args) {
                console.log('Calling Ajout_BDD: args: ' + JSON.stringify(args));
                return { output: { Ajout_BDDReturn : true } };
            }
        }
    }
}

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('example-service-original.wsdl', 'utf8');

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url);
});

server.listen(8001);
var soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/mdworksService', service, xml);
soapServer.log = function(type, data) {
    // type is 'received' or 'replied'
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": " + type + ': ' + data);
};
```

Again, you'll need to include the WSDL file in the same dir as the server. This approach can be very useful for testing SOAP clients.